# C# test application

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c++-cli

I a have a solution containing 25 projects comprised of both C# and managed C++.

I need to test one of the C# project calls but this project is of type "Window application" (Not DLL).

Even though it is a windows application, my requirement is to call only few internal functional calls (Not related to windows form).

I need to create a separate C# test project to call this functionality. Is it possible to do it like this?

Can anyone suggest a way or examples? And one more thing, I cannot modify the existing code.

Comment: Have you tried it? Create a project, reference the windows app. Call the methods you want. _very easy_.

Comment: It might be possible. It depends.

Comment: You can reference them into your project and use them in any language such as C#, VB, C++.

Comment: reference the windows means adding its exe? or just adding required file names?

Comment: Reference the Visual Studio project (Right-click project -> "Add Reference..." Solution - Project)

Comment: Thank you. I will come back to you if further clarification required

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do it like this?

Yes. Referencing the project you wish to test in a test project is typically how you unit test your code.

> Can any one suggest a way or examples?

Create a unit test project, reference the project that contains the code you wish to test, write tests to test the code you wish to test. If you need to refactor the code to make it testable, do so, or see point below.

> And one more thing, i don't have any freedom to modify the existing
>   source code.

In this case, you are going to have to wrap the code in some cleaner interfaces to allow you to test the code.

The book, [Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) has some excellent advice on how to get legacy code under test.